# How to disable CollectionView live sorting and filtering?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with the `ItemSource` bound to an object of type `ICollectionView`. The data source for this object is an `ObservableCollection`. The view is filtered on request and a `ListCollectionView` is created and used to sort the data. Sorting and filtering the data i working as expected. When a filter is set or custom sorter is set the data is filtered and sorted "live" in the `DataGrid` and this is a feature that I want to disable. What I mean is that the `DataGrid` changes when a user edit the data in the grid due to the filter and sorter. I thougth that this hade something to do with the properties `List​Collection​View.​Is​Live​Sorting` and `ListCollectionView.IsLiveFiltering` but both those are set to false. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Also I think that the update of the GUI is relatively slow after filtering and sorting. The `DataGrid` has 23 columns and a sort or filter action of 1500 elements takes approximately 300 ms each, but the GUI update takes about 2 seconds. But this might be an unrelated problem but I thought that I should mention it.

Partial code from my ViewModel:

```
public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; private set; }
public ICollectionView CollectionViewUnsorted { get; private set; }
public ListCollectionView ListCollectionView { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Connection> ConnectionData { get; private set; }


public ConnectionsViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;    
    this.PropertyChanged = ConnectionsViewModelPropertyChanged;

    List<Connection> cList = ImportElprocadCSVFiles.ImportConnectionList("fullständig_rapport.csv");

    ConnectionData = new ObservableCollection<Connection>(cList);
    CollectionView = new ListCollectionView(ConnectionData);
    ListCollectionView = CollectionView as ListCollectionView;
    ListCollectionView.IsLiveFiltering = false;
    ListCollectionView.IsLiveSorting = false;

    SetSortCommand = new RelayCommand(SetSort);
    UnsetSortCommand = new RelayCommand(UnsetSort);

}

private void SetSort()
{
    ListCollectionView.CustomSort = new CableNumberComparer();
    CollectionView.Refresh();
}

private void UnsetSort()
{
    ListCollectionView.CustomSort = null;
    CollectionView.Refresh();
}
```

Partial XAML:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Right" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="4"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" 
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" FontFamily="Console">
```

Comment: If you don't want the order of anything to change then set datagrid.canusersort to false. Do any sorting and filtering in linq rather than the collectionview.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear. Actually I want the user to be able to sort but I want to turn off the live sorting that is triggered when a property of an item in the collection is changed. Also want do disable automatic sorting triggered by a collection change. The same goes for filtering, I do not want the view to be automatically filtered. I want the view to be updated only when `CollectionView.Refresh()` is called

Comment: @J.Thor what if you set CanUserSort to false in the viewmodel's constructor, then unset at the start of your commands and reset at the end of the command?

Comment: @J.Thor did you found solution for disabling live filtering?